# Particleground.js: how to make website scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, particles

I'm making a website and planning to use

> Particleground.js

plugin at the entrance for my site. I've downloaded it [here](https://github.com/jnicol/particleground) and used according to demo file. But in demo there is only one `<div>`, so they have a fulscreen particles + text. While I need something like [that](http://aliensix.com/particles-1.4/HTML/index-default-particles.html), i.e. scrollable landing page with particles at the top. Thanks in advance for your help!

That's how my container looks at the moment:

```
<div id="particles">
  <div class="uk-section uk-uk-padding-medium" id="intro">
    <div class="uk-container uk-padding-large">
      <!-- content here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then follows next container, and I cannot scroll there!

Here are CSS settings:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}

#particles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

#intro {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, we found what was the problem (easy). In CSS it should be like this:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
/*   overflow: hidden; */
}
```

This `overflow:hidden;`was making things so complicated, so just remove it.